# LaTeX Longtable bug: header-only page generated: how do I fix?

Tags: header-footer, longtable

here is my LaTeX: (how does one format it nicely?):
[Edit:] Reducing the example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lscape}
\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\noindent 
\begin{longtable}{ll}
\caption[]{Decomposition } \\ 
  &   \\ \endhead\hline
 & 
$ \begin{array}{l}
1 \\ +1 \\ +1 \\ +1 \\ +1 \\ +1 \\ +1 \\ +1 \\ +1 \\ +1 \\ +1 \\ +1 \\ +1 \\ +1 \\ +1 \\ +1 \\ +1 \\ +1 \\ +1 \\ +1 \\ +1 \\ +1 \\ +1 \\ +1 \\ +1 \\ +1 \\ +1 \\ +1 \\ 
\end{array}$
\end{longtable}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

And here is what I get:
[latest reduced example](http://www.2shared.com/document/k_BU3RS9/lontableBUG.html)

[original example .pdf](http://www.2shared.com/document/75U1XCom/lontableBUG.html)

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1192/how-do-i-mark-code-blocks). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it). Your example is also rather long: it would be best to construction a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

Comment: I have something closer to a MWE now. Don't know whether the landscape environment is an issue or not.

Comment: A longtable can have a page break only after a tabular line and this is _before_ your long array which is for longtable _one_ tabular line. You have to insert a manually page break.

Answer (score 3):

It's clear that there is an error in the title of your question (my packages only have undocumented features *never* bugs:-)

You can use `array` package to make the longtable column math mode, then get rid of the inner `array` so that the table can break as you wish:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable,array}
\usepackage{lscape}
\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}

\begin{longtable}{l>{$}l<{$}}
\caption[]{Decomposition } \\ 
  &   \\ \endhead\hline
&1 \\& +1 \\& +1 \\& +1 \\& +1 \\& +1 \\& +1 \\& +1 \\& +1 \\& +1 \\& +1 \\& +1 \\& +1 \\& +1 \\& +1 \\& +1 \\& +1 \\& +1 \\& +1 \\& +1 \\& +1 \\& +1 \\& +1 \\& +1 \\& +1 \\& +1 \\& +1 \\& +1
\end{longtable}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! "It's clear that there is an error in the title of your question" >:) it was attention-seeking :) - glad it worked and sorry if it was too provocative :)